# php oci8 throw error when running script by php command

Tags: php, linux, oracle, oci8

(Sorry for my poor English. I wish someone could read.)

I have deployed php with oci8 on my machine.

1. I prepared test script to connect oracle db server, below is the content  of test.php.

   ```
       $conn = oci_connect('pay', 'pay', "(DESCRIPTION=(ADDRESS_LIST=(ADDRESS=(PROTOCOL=TCP)(HOST=MY_IP)(PORT=MY_PORT)))(CONNECT_DATA=(SID=MY_SID)(UR=A)))");

   if (!$conn) {
       $e = oci_error();
       trigger_error(htmlentities($e['message'], ENT_QUOTES), E_USER_ERROR);
   }
   ```

   ...
2. I try to run it by visiting **on browser. it connected successfully,** fetched data from the db as well.

**3. But when I run it by using php command,**

```
 php test.php
```

**it gave me an error:** Call to undefined function oci_connect() in test.php on line 3. I have no idea, that's weird.

Anyone can tell me why?

Comment: This is probably because you different configuration files are being used. Run the command `php --ini` and compare the returned paths with the output of `phpinfo()` from your web server.

Comment: Thanks. You've got a point. it's about php.ini. It worked after I adding extension=oci8.so to the end of the file.


Well the digression is that the php.ini that I modified is the same one to the output of phpini(); since it was not able to work before I adding the extension line, why it worked when I visited it on brower, when and where the oci8.so was loaded at that time.